# How does this give a vector bundle?!?

Tags: vector-bundles, tangent-bundle

My text says that the map $p:S^2\to \text{Idem}( \text{Mat}_3(\Bbb R))$ given by $p(x)v=v-\langle x,v\rangle x$ defines a vector bundle $E(p)$ on $S^2$.

So I assume that $E(p)=\bigcup_xp(x)\subset \text{Idem}( \text{Mat}_3(\Bbb R))$ and the vector bundle projection is $\pi:E(p)\to S^2, p(x)\mapsto x$. But this map isn't continuous since $p(x_n)\to p(x)$ only implies $x_n\to \pm x$.

What is going on here?

Comment: What's Idem? And a vector bundle is defined by $\pi : V \to \mathbb S^2$. So your $p$ definitely is not the projection map of a vector bundle

Comment: idem is the idempotents

Comment: That's what I'm saying...the only way I can interpret what they write is that the projection map is the map $\pi$ that i defined above. But that thing isn't continuous so i am confused

Comment: What text are you using?

Comment: Lecture notes actually

Comment: One interpretation could be that one consider $\ker p(x) \subset \mathbb R^3$. This forms a vector bundle on $\mathbb S^2$ and is just the tangent bundle. In any case you might want to confuse the lecturer instead.(or $\text{Im} p(x)$)

Comment: How does that form a vector bundle? Is $E(p)= \bigcup_x \ker p(x)$? Why is the projection continuous then?

Comment: Yes, that's the vector bundle I was referring to. Note fiber at $x\in \mathbb S^2$ is the vector space perpendicular to $x$, this is quite obviously condinuous (but of course one has to first defines a topology on the set $E(p)$ and then proves continuity. This shouldn't be difficult)

Comment: $E(p)$ just has the subspace topology of $\Bbb R^3$ right?

Comment: @JohnMa The projection is not well defined......$v\in \ker p(x)$ is also an element of $\ker p(-x)$ so it maps to two different elements under the projection

Comment: Is $E(p) = \bigcup_{x\in S^2} \{x\} \times \ker p(x)$

Comment: Yes ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 0):

Is there a $\langle x, x \rangle $ term missing?
Notice then $\langle x, p(x)v \rangle = \langle x, v \rangle - \langle x , v \rangle = 0$. So what you have is the Normal bundle.

Comment: Note $\langle x, x\rangle  =1$.

Comment: Oops, of course!